# Cast em sockets

Tags: c, socket

Galera queria entender qual motivo de fazer esses cast abaixo, é apenas por estética? O que realmente isso afeta no código?

```
struct iphdr *ip; 

char *buffer    

ip = (struct iphdr*) packet;

icmp = (struct icmphdr*) (packet + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extraído da resposta do SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620771/3134655

A estrutura `iphdr` é utilizada para acessar diretamente a estrutura de um pacote [IP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_Internet).

No trecho de código abaixo (extraído da referência acima):

```
struct iphdr *ip, *ip_reply;
char *packet, *buffer;

packet = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct icmphdr));
buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct icmphdr));
ip = (struct iphdr*) packet;
icmp = (struct icmphdr*) (packet + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

Primeiramente, é necessário alocar a memória com o comando `malloc`.

Como esse comando retorna um ponteiro do tipo `void *` armazenado na variável `packet`, que é do tipo `char *` (um buffer genérico), o cast é necessário para referenciar o buffer `packet` (por exemplo) com o tipo correto:

`struct iphdr *`.

Através dessa referência, é possível atribuir os valores corretamente a cada membro da estrutura:

```
ip->ihl         = 5;
ip->version     = 4;
ip->tot_len     = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct icmphdr);
ip->protocol    = IPPROTO_ICMP;
ip->saddr       = inet_addr(src_addr);
ip->daddr       = inet_addr(dst_addr);
ip->check = in_cksum((unsigned short *)ip, sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

Para maiores referências (em inglês):

https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/

Comment: Gomiero quando faço o cast como ip = (struct iphdr*) packet , a variavel packet é modelada com  os membros da estrutura iphdr?

Comment: @user37361 Não. Do começo: o `malloc` reserva um espaço (bloco) na memória, que não passa de uma sequência de bytes. Quando você faz um `cast`, de forma simples, você está "explicando" para o compilador `C` como ele vai enxergar esse bloco de bytes. Exemplo fictício: os 4 primeiros bytes do bloco formam um número inteiro (`int`), os próximos 8 são um número ponto flutuante (`double`), e assim por diante.

Answer (score 6):

## Porque usar *cast* onde parece não precisar

Só com um trecho não dá para explicar muito, mas é pouco provável que seja só estética, até porque não vi onde fica mais bonito. *Cast* desnecessário só costuma ser feito por quem não sabe programar (tem exceções).

Muitas vezes **o *cast* não faz um conversão nenhuma**, apenas informa ao compilador que o programador está ciente que a operação ali envolve o uso de uma informação que pode ser originalmente diferente mas que ele quer usar como um tipo definido.

Alguns compiladores podem não reclamar, mas é mais seguro que seja emitido pelo menos um *warning* que a operação é potencialmente equivocada. Obrigar ser explícito é uma forma de evitar *bugs*. Por sorte hoje os compiladores costumam exigir que o *cast* seja feito para garantir que é esta a intenção mesmo.

## O que este código faz

Este código está lendo um pacote de TCP/IP que nada mais é um uma enorme sequência de *bytes* (um *buffer*) com algum significado apenas para o protocolo. Conhecedor do protocolo, o programador entende quais são os blocos desta enorme sequência que indicam determinada informação contida dentro do protocolo.

O que este código está fazendo é pegar cada um destes blocos e atribuí-lo a uma variável cada.

Como ele faz isto?

Ele pega o endereço do pacote onde consta a primeira informação, O IP. Então ele joga um ponteiro na variável `ip` do código que apontará para o primeiro bloco do pacote, é lá que se encontra o IP do pacote.

Como este ponteiro não tem significado para o código, pode ser que não seja o que deva fazer. Então o compilador exige que se coloque o *cast* para informar que você quer que este ponteiro "arbitrário" seja considerado um ponteiro para a estrutura `iphdr`.

O mesmo pode se dizer para *cast* seguinte para a variável `icmp`. Ali  está está fazendo um deslocamento do endereço inicialmente obtido para **mapear** para outra estrutura (note que o deslocamento é exatamente o tamanho da primeira informação). Ou seja, ele vai apontar para o segundo bloco de informação contido no pacote. O *cast* serve para indicar ao compilador que este valor apontado nesta sequência pode ser lido tranquilamente como um "ponteiro para uma estrutura `icmphdr`".

Ele não precisaria necessariamente criar diversas variáveis isoladas para cada bloco de informação do protocolo. Ele poderia jogar esta informação em um estrutura desenhada especificamente para receber as informações do protocolo. Em alguns cenários isto é o mais correto a fazer. Neste caso o *cast* em cada item nem seria necessário. O *layout*  de um pacote TCP/IP é praticamente uma `struct` pronta. Claro que se for realizar algumas conversões não pode aproveitar o pacote inteiro para mapear direto na estrutura, mas se precisa de conversão de dados, o pacote não pode ser usado para o apontamento.